# getting the prefix of a number in python

Tags: python, class

I am new to python programming and i am working on a project.

I have a list with prefix and price. Its look like this

```
LIST 1                   LIST2
prefix      price         prefix     price
44          5.7           44         3.5
45          3.8           45         5.6
678         4             78         1.0
6543        2             6543       1.5
12          8
```

and so on...

I have the above one in a class object.

The input is the phone numbers. I can give a phone number "4673345677" or "6543346874" and i have to find the cheapest price for the given number. One other condition is that, if a number satisfies several prefixes the longest prefix should be used.

This is the structure of the python class i am working on:

```
class CallPrice:
    def __init__(self,prefix,price):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.price = price

    def getPrefixLength(self):
        return len(self.prefix)
```

I tried to split the input phone number and compare the prefix, but my logic fails. Can anyone please help me out with this logic or point me in the right direction?

Comment: We need some example input and output to be able to solve this

Comment: do you want a way to extract the largest prefix from a given number ?

Comment: Are both lists in the same input file?  I'm confused as to what you're parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I'd probably build a list of dicts.

```
price_lists = [ [{'44': 5.7}, {'45': 3.8}, ...],
                [{'44': 3.5}, {'45': 5.6}, ...] ] # list1's dicts, then list2's
```

Do some quick preprocessing of your dictionary:

```
prefix_lengths = {len(key) for sublst in price_lists for dct in sublst for key in dct}
```

Then build some function that takes a phone number and returns its prefix, based on how many characters. This is basically just an alias to the less-readable string slice.

```
def prefix_with_length(length, phonenum):
    return phonenum.replace('-','')[:length]
    # I also drop hyphens for a more robust code
```

Finally iterate through your lists.

```
phone_number = "1-800-555-1234"
_result = result = float('inf')
for price_list in price_lists:

    _result = min(price_list[prefix_with_length(length, phone_number)] for length in prefix_lengths)
    # _result is the lowest price in that sublist
    result = min(_result, result)
    # result is the lowest so far
```

Unfortunately this question is pretty unclear. I'm not sure what you're comparing between, whether you're trying to ONLY use the longest prefix or compare between prefixes, what counts as a prefix, whether your phone numbers are strings or numbers (they should be strings!) or any of a dozen other factors that could change what you're trying to do. Could you please be more specific?

If you're trying to compare between lists, try combining prefixes.

```
lists = [ [('44',5.7), ('45': 3.8), ... ], [('44', 3.5), ('45': 5.6), ...] ]
prefix_dict = {}
for lst in lists:
    for key,value in lst:
        prefix_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(value)
prefixes = sorted(prefix_dict.keys(), key=lambda x: len(x), reversed=True)

phone_number = '18005551234'
for prefix in prefixes:
    if phone_number.startswith(prefix):
        result = min(prefix_dict[prefix])
        break
else:
    # handle no result
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a dictionary instead, with key-value pairs.

Example:

```
example_dictionary = {'prefix1' : price1, 'prefix2' : price2}
```

The only problem with a dictionary is that you can't use the same key twice. To solve this you could instead put multiple values for each key.
So instead of 'prefix1' : price1, you could do 'prefix1' : [price1, price2].

EDIT: Okay so I tested some sample code, here it is:

```
example_dictionary = {'065875': [1, 2, 4, 5], '06587': [1, 5, 70]}


cheapest_value = get_cheapest_value('0658')

def get_cheapest_value(number):

    prefix_storage = []

    for prefix in example_dictionary:
        if number in prefix:
            prefix_storage.append(prefix)

    prefix = [i for i in prefix_storage if len(i)==max([len(n) for n in prefix_storage])]

    prefix = prefix[0]

    return min(example_dictionary.get(prefix))
```

Comment: this does not help to get the prefix from a number.

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? It is a very unclear question, and I answered it the best I could.